# Laravel 5.4 connect two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, relational-database

> First table (leads)

id, website, name, user_id

> Second table (flags)

id, lead_id, user_id, info

> What I am trying to do

Get all the **user flags** and each flag **lead information**.

> what I have tried

**Flag model**

```
public function main() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Main', 'lead_id');
}
```

**Flag Controller**

```
public function getAgentFlags()
{
    $agent_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $flags = Flag::whereHas('main', function ($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    })->get();
    dd($flags);

    $totalleads = Flag::where('user_id', '=', $agent_id)->count();

    return view('flags.my-flags')
        ->withLeads($leads)
        ->withTotalleads($totalleads);
}
```

> What it returns

It returned wrong information as it return leads which is **not equal** to user **ID**.

Comment: Why is the model for your `leads` table called `Main`?

Comment: @RossWilson it was a mistake but how I do it with that name?